# I tried to center the logo for phone but it only works on firefox, not on chrome, why?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navigation, centering

Github live:

https://luffydrank.github.io/FreeCodeCamp-Product-Landing-Page/

Github repository:

https://github.com/LuffyDrank/FreeCodeCamp-Product-Landing-Page

What I just said, I tried to center it on chrome with the media query and it didn't work out, except what a friend did that was erasing completely `.nav-left` and erasing the "padding" and "height" attributes from the `.nav` and change the "justify-content" to center, it wasn't working at first but after I closed and opened the live server it worked, really weird.

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 45px 20px;
    height: 50px;
}
.nav-right {
    width: 70%;
}
.nav-left {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 30%;
}
.nav-right ul {
    display: flex;
    gap: 30px;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.728rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav-right ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #EA6129;
    padding: 5px;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
}

.nav-right ul a:hover{
    color: #f8daac;
    background-color: #fd551b;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#welcome {
    padding: 150px 0px 100px 0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 80vh;
    background-image: url(./images/burger-unsplashdark.jpg);
    background-size: 100vw 100%;
}
#welcome-text {
    margin: 50px;
}
#welcome-title {
    font-size: 2.488rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5%;
}

#welcome-subtitle {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.93);
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5%;
}
#welcome-img {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 50px;
    border-radius: 5%;
    padding: 20px;
}
.acerca-div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    gap: 50px;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#logo {
    height: 150px; 
}
.icon {
    width: 100px
}
.icon2 {
    width: 50px
}
#acerca {
    padding: 50px;
    background-image:url(./images/stars-unplash.jpg);
    object-fit: cover;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 75px;
}
.menu {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-image:url(./images/table-unplash.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.menu-img {
    width: 40vw;
}

.menu-div {
    margin: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.media {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#contacto {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 50px;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.center {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    gap: 10px;
    color: #EA6129;
}
.center p {
    padding: 10px;
}
.center p:hover {
    color: #f8daac;
    background-color: #fd551b;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.contacto-icons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    padding: 25px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.contacto-location {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    padding: 25px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
}

.image-carousel-img {
    width: 40vw;
}
#contacto {
     background-image:url(./images/stars-unplash.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

#map {
    width: 50vw;
}

video {
    display: none;
}
.media {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-image:url(./images/stars-unplash.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    padding: 50px;
    gap: 10px;
}

footer {
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
}

.footer a{
    color: #fd551b;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;
}
.footer a:hover {
    color: #f8daac;
    background-color: #fd551b;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.footer h1 {
    margin: 0px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .nav-right {
        display: none;
    }
    .nav {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-content: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="FreeCodeCamp project">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>Product Landing Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="nav-left">
                <img id="logo" src="./images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
            </div>
            <div class="nav-right">
                <ul>
                    <a href="#acerca"><li>Acerca de nosotros</li></a>
                    <a href="#menu"><li>Menu</li></a>
                    <a href="#contacto"><li>Contacto</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        </nav>
        <main>
            <section>
            <div id="welcome">
                <div id="welcome-text">
                <h1 id="welcome-title">La mejor comida rapida en Chivacoa</h1>
                <p id="welcome-subtitle">Disfruta de las mejores hamburguesas y de los mejores perros calientes de la zona</p>
            </div>
            <img id="welcome-img" src="./images/comida4.jpg" alt="Foto de hamburguesas">
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div id="acerca">
            <div class="acerca-div">
                <img class="icon"  src="./images/2295341.png" alt="">
                <div>
                <h1>Comida de calidad</h1>
                    <p>Nos encargamos de comprar solamente a marcas confiables para realizar nuestra comida,
                        las cuales aseguran la calidad y hiene de los alimentos
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="acerca-div">
                <img class="icon" src="./images/2295343.png" alt="">
                <div>
                 <h1>El mejor sabor</h1>
                    <p>Realizamos una gran comida para disfrutar con tus amigos familia o pareja</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="acerca-div">
                <img class="icon" src="./images/2295342-2.png"" alt="">
                <div>
                    <h1>Al mejor precio</h1>
                    <p>Ofrecemos un increible precio por nuestra comida, ¡no te lo pierdas!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div id ="menu" class="menu">
            <div class="menu-div">
            <img class="menu-img" src="./images/comida.jpg" alt="">
            <h2>
                Hamburguesa La Especial
            </h2>
            <p>
                Lechuga Y tomate
            </p>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-div">
                <img class="menu-img" src="./images/comida.jpg" alt="">
                <h2>
                    Perro Normal
                </h2>
                <p>
                    Salchicha
                </p>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-div">
                    <img class="menu-img" src="./images/comida.jpg" alt="">
                    <h2>
                        Hamburguesa Normal
                    </h2>
                    <p>
                        Lechuga
                    </p>
                    </div>

        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div id="contacto">
            <div class="contacto-icons">
            <a class="center" target="_blank" href="https://www.a00b.com/"><img class="icon2" src="./images/facebook.svg" alt=""><p>Facebook</p></a>
            <a class="center" target="_blank" href="https://www.kelid1.ir"><img class="icon2" src="./images/whatsapp.svg" alt=""><p>04120586545</p></a>
            <a class="center" target="_blank" href="https://wa.me/584125618239"><img class="icon2" src="./images/whatsapp.svg" alt=""><p>04125618239</p></a>
            <a class="center" target="_blank" href="https://l.messenger.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Finstagram.com%2Ftonysburguerrestaurant%3Figshid%3DYmMyMTA2M2Y%253D&h=AT1oKhmXMGzO7W6QbzarGqNW21grgXSDWEK10e2nzW5zLngj5Fow5bd0Dzv4uW1pGLzYuI9dPBOWXSIyzDzQUGvBV0S-T6txT409OBOSEKDJ_x_y8TjBitG45KkTcphGyvez1Q"><img class="icon2" src="./images/instagram.svg" alt=""><p>Instagram</p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="contacto-location">
            <h2>Avenida 5 entre calle 10 y 11 Chivacoa Yaracuy</h2>
        </div>
            <iframe id="map" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d15709.037785755107!2d-68.8942656!3d10.1595538!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xd4139ed8d2ec512b!2sTony&#39;s%20Burguer%20Restaurant!5e0!3m2!1ses-419!2sve!4v1662776058859!5m2!1ses-419!2sve" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="media">
            <video src="" alt=""></video>
                <img class="image-carousel-img" src="./images/lugar.jpg" alt="">       
                <img class="image-carousel-img" src="./images/lugar.jpg" alt="">   
                <img class="image-carousel-img" src="./images/lugar.jpg" alt="">   
                <img class="image-carousel-img" src="./images/lugar.jpg" alt="">   
        </div>
    </section>
        </main>
        <footer>
            <div class="footer">
                <h1>Website made by <a href="">LuffyDrank</a></h1>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works fine for me on chrome

Comment: The logo is centered in the viewport OK for me on narrow viewports. What version of Chrome are you using? And what device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually did center. maybe somehow I accidentally changed some settings and the width it showed me wasn't all of it. I noticed when I moved the screen from left to right that it actually centers and that I must have changed some screen width related option (?), so nothing was wrong with the code it was just browser related settings it seems.

It actually does center sorry, steps I did to make it work as I wanted it to (default)

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32695917)

Comment: @DeenadhayalanManoharan This is a link to Stack Overflows Imgur instance. How else should a screenshot be included than that?